# How to save an image from ds9 as a region file to use it some other time?

Tags: regions

I'm trying to save a ds9 image as a region file but after I saved it I can't open it using ds9.here is how I did it:regions,save regions,then ok(format=ds9 and coordinate system fk5). where is the problem?any help please?Or any system may be using the command line is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. Silly trick but even though the save as file type defaults to .reg, you have to actually type in ".reg" at the end of the file name.

So do what you've been doing ,regions-> save regions-> etc etc. then just add in .reg at the end of the filename you pick.